# jquery, css not changes before long time exec function

Tags: jquery, css, function, time

```js
function doact() {
  $('p.main').addClass("hide");
  $('p.loading').removeClass("hide");

  //this is only example of long time exec function
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {}
  }
  //

  $('p.loading').addClass("hide");
  $('p.main').removeClass("hide");

  alert('done');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="loading hide">loading...</p>
<p class="main">bla bla bla</p>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="do action" onclick="doact()" />
```

When I click the button, `loading...` does not appear and `main` does not disappear, only done message.
How can implement such an algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because JS is single-threaded. Hence the renderer does not get enough time to re-paint the UI before it starts the huge loop. It then can only update *after* the loop completes, at which time it hides the element, then shows it again straight away, hence nothing appears to happen.

To fix this, run the blocking code in a `setTimeout()` with a slight delay which gives the UI time to update before starting the loop.

Also note that `on*` event attributes should be avoided. I've amended your code to use an unobtrusive JS handler, as you have included jQuery anyway:

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('p.main, p.loading').toggleClass("hide");

  setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {}
    }

    $('p.main, p.loading').toggleClass("hide");
    console.log('done');
  }, 50);
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="loading hide">loading...</p>
<p class="main">bla bla bla</p>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="do action" />
```

With that said, **long-running synchronous operations which block the UI are a very bad pattern**. I'd strongly suggest refactoring your code so that you avoid this.